# How validate the Formspree with jquery Validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, validation

I've a form with Formspree, but isn't getting validate with [jQuery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/).

This is my HTML code:

```
<form class="form" id="contactForm" action="//formspree.io/myemail@email.com" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Your name" required>
    <input type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Email" required>
    <input type="tel" name="Phone" placeholder="Phone">
    <input type="text" name="Subject" placeholder="Subject">
    <textarea name="Message" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
    <!-- CONFIG -->
    <input class="is-hidden" type="text" name="_gotcha">
    <input type="hidden" name="_subject" value="Contact by Site">
    <input type="hidden" name="_cc" value="cc@email.com">
    <!-- /CONFIG -->
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

This is my JS code:

```
(function() {

    // FORM / CONTACT

    var $contactForm = $('#contactForm');
    // VALIDATE FORM
    $contactForm.validate();
    $contactForm.submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '//formspree.io/myemail@mail.com',
            method: 'POST',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function() {
                $contactForm.append('<div class="message message--loading">Sending message…</div>');
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $contactForm.find('.alert--loading').hide();
                $contactForm.append('<div class="message message--success">Message sent!</div>');
            },
            error: function(err) {
                $contactForm.find('.alert--loading').hide();
                $contactForm.append('<div class="message message--error">Ops, there was an error.</div>');
            }
        });
    });
})();
```

In the moment, the message is sent same with fields in white. In my case the validation appears only with CSS, but not prohibit the user from sending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not prevent the submit !

```
(function() {
    var $contactForm = $('#contactForm');
    // VALIDATE FORM
    $contactForm.validate();
    $contactForm.submit(function(e) {
        if ($(this).valid())
             {...}
       return false;
     });
})();
```